# One line while-loop in bash creating list of variables

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop, scripting

I am attempting to write a 1 line while loop that creates a string of file names like list="temp0.txt temp1.txt temp2.txt ... " etc..  I want it to be a random number of files between 0 and 50, and this is what I have thus far.

```
argumentCount=$RANDOM
let "argumentCount %= 50"
i=0
list=""
while [ $i -lt $argumentCount ]; do; touch temp[$i].txt; $list="$list temp[$i].txt; ((i=i+1)); done
countLines $list > output.txt
```

I am trying to declare a random number between 0 and 50, and then using a while loop I want to create the same number of files as this random number. I want to then create a string that has all of the file names listed one after the other. This string will then be passed to 
countLines, which is a program that accepts any number of filenames as parameters.

I have this set of commands stored in a different file, and I am using eval on each line in this file, but it is giving me a syntax error. Is there something I can do to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: `printf -v varname "temp%03d.txt" $(($RANDOM % 50))` Then `$varname` will contain `temp000.txt` - `temp049.txt` randomly. (you can control the number of leading `'0'`s with the `printf` *format specifier*. (add `$(($RANDOM % 50 + 1))` for `001 - 050` numbering).

Comment: I am looking to make multiple files, but a random number of files.

Comment: @SeanMorgan: Can you provide a minimal verifiable input and expected output. Your current code/requirement is not clear. State exactly your input and output required

Comment: You need some exit condition for your loop. You just can't continue to randomly create files forever. You can use a counter (e.g. `declare -i n=0`) and in  your file-create loop to `((n++))` and `test "$n" -gt '40' && break` if you like. (or whatever number you like). You also need to check for an existing file of the same name/number (e.g. `test -f "$varname" && continue` to generate a non-conflicting filename)

Comment: In your existing while loop line, try dropping the ';' after do and '$' in '$list='

Comment: @mittal Thank you, that seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

This will print a line with file names:

```
eval echo temp{1..$((RANDOM%50))}.txt
```

And this will touch the list of files:

```
eval touch temp{1..$((RANDOM%50))}.txt
```

And this script will do all the things yours do:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=$( eval echo '"temp["{1..'$((RANDOM%50))'}"].txt"' )

touch $list

countLines "$list" > output.txt
```